# How to replace all characters in a string except first and last characters, using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write a solution in JavaScript to replace all the characters in a string with a *, except for the first and last characters. I'm not very familiar with RegEx but was trying to use the following to achieve the solution:

```
var regex = /\.(?=^)(?!=$)/;
    const censored = w.replace(regex)
    console.log(censored)
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Does it *have* to use a regex or could you use the first char, a string of (string length - 2) asterisks, and the last char?

Comment: It doesn't have to use regex! I thought that would be the easiest way but perhaps not.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53747972/3832970).

Answer (score 12):

The idea of using lookaheads is viable, let's correct a few mistakes:

```js
var regex = /(?<!^).(?!$)/g;
var w = 'fork'
var censored = w.replace(regex, '*')

console.log(censored)
```

Do note, however, that lookbehinds (`?<=` and `?<!`) are from ES 2018 and not universally supported yet. (As pointed out in another answer, you actually don't need a lookbehind here, a lookahead `(?!^)` would do as well). Stil...

You can also chop off the first char and replace the rest:

```js
var w = 'fork'
var censored = w[0] + w.slice(1).replace(/.(?!$)/g, '*')

console.log(censored)
```

Finally, here's a way to do that without any regexes at all:

```js
var w = 'fork'
var censored = w[0] + '*'.repeat(w.length - 2) + w.slice(-1)

console.log(censored)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way without regex:

```js
function censor(str) {
  return str[0] + new Array(str.length - 2).join('*') + str[str.length - 1]
}

console.log(censor('happy birthday'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a replace callback as the second parameter to replace the items like this:

```js
const str = 'fork'

var result = str.replace(/^(.)(.+)(.)$/, (whole, first, middle, last) => {
  return first + new Array(middle.length).fill('*').join('') + last
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy with an ECMAScript 5 compliant regex pattern:

```js
var regex = /(?!^)[\s\S](?!$)/g;
var w = "Text!"
var censored = w.replace(regex, "*")
console.log(censored)
```

**Details**

- `(?!^)` - negative lookahead: matches a location that is not a string start position
- `[\s\S]` - any char (even a newline)
- `(?!$)` - negative lookahead: matches a location that is not a string end position

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/ZR85C4/1).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution if regex is not a requirement.

```js
function censor(input){
  return input.split("").map(function(char, index){
    if(index === 0 || index === (input.length - 1)){
      return char;
    } else {
      return "*";
    }
  }).join("");
}

console.log(censor("Hello world"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following code:

```
(?<=\w{1})\w(?=\w{1})
```

where `?<=` is positive lookbehind, and `?=` is a positive lookahead