# How do I mask an email address between the first and the last character before the @ sign?

Tags: javascript

My goal is to edit the string (which has an email) to mask the first part, like say the email is `johndoe@abc.com` then I should output `j*****e@abc.com`.

```
var maskPII = function(S) {
    var ans = "";
    if(S.includes("@")){
        S = S.toLowerCase();
        var parts = S.split("@");
        var first = parts[0];
        for(var i=0;i<parts[0].length;i++){
            if(i!=0 && i!=parts[0].length - 1)
                first[i] = '*';
        }
        ans = first +"@" +parts[1];
    }else{

    }
    return ans;
};
```

However in my loop I can't change the characters to asterisks.

After execution I see value of first still same as `parts[0]` and has no asterisks, can some one explain why? Also, what would I need to do to modify the variable inside loop?

Comment: Could you post the entire block including where `parts` and `first` are defined?

Comment: please share the value of parts[0]

Comment: Could you please add what parts[] and first[] is?

Comment: Without a runnable [mcve] that demonstrates your issue we are left to simply guessing which isn't productive for any of us

Comment: added whole code

Comment: And some  sample data to run this against? If you click on `<>` in question editor you can even make it runnable here in the page as well as console.log() what you want

Comment: You can't replace characters in a string like that. Strings are immutable. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53747640/how-to-replace-all-characters-in-a-string-except-first-and-last-characters-usin) solution.

Comment: Yes Ivar, you are right I later found that strings are immutable, thanks

Comment: you should be using something like splice for this anyways

Answer (score 0):

Well, this's what you're looking for, and this will be the output `j*****e@abc.com`.

```js
var ans = "";
var S = "johndoe@abc.com"; //example
S = S.toLowerCase();
var parts = S.split("@");
var first = "";
for(var i = 0; i < parts[0].length; i++){
  if(i != 0 && i != parts[0].length - 1){
      first += '*';
  }else{
      first += parts[0][i];
  }
}

ans = first +"@"+ parts[1];
console.log(ans);
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question...  javascript allows you access values of a string using [] indexing.. but that is read only access... you cannot insert/replace values using that operator.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

```
When using bracket notation for character access,
attempting to delete or assign a value to these properties will not succeed.
The properties involved are neither writable nor configurable.
(See Object.defineProperty() for more information.)
```

You need to extract the values you want to keep from the existing string and build up a new string as noted in other answers...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code with your approach:

```js
var maskPII = function(S) {
    var ans = "";
    if(S.includes("@")){
        S = S.toLowerCase();
        var parts = S.split("@");
        var first = parts[0][0];
        for(var i=0;i<parts[0].length;i++){
            if(i!=0 && i!=parts[0].length - 1)
                first += '*';
        }
        ans = first + parts[0][parts[0].length - 1] +"@" +parts[1];
    }else{

    }
    return ans;
};
```

But if i were you i would use:

```js
var mail = "johndoe@abc.com";
mail = mail.replace(/(?<=.)(.+?)(?=.@)/gi, '*'.repeat(mail.split('@')[0].length - 2));
console.log(mail);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bracket notation on a string (like an array) to *get* the character at a specific index, but you can't use this to *change* characters. So `first[i] = '*'` in your code wont do anything.

Strings in JavaScript are immutable. This means that if you want to change a string, a new string instance will be created. This also means that when you change a string in a for-loop, it can impact performance. (Although in this case the difference wont be noticeable.
)

I would use this code:

```js
function maskPII(str) {
  const indexOfAt = str.indexOf('@');
  if (indexOfAt <= 2) {
    return str;
  }

  return str[0] + '*'.repeat(indexOfAt - 2) + str.substring(indexOfAt - 1);
}

const email = 'johndoe@abc.com';
console.log(email);
console.log(maskPII(email));
```

It will look for the index of the `@` sign. If the index is less or equal than 2, (when not found the index will be `-1`) it will return the original string.

Otherwise it will get the first character, calculate the amount of asterisks needed (index of the `@` sign -2) and repeat those and then add the rest of the original string.